# What is the probability distribution p that maximizes the overlap between the distribution p and its Gaussian convolution?

Tags: probability, integration, optimization, normal-distribution, convolution

The question is for a given variance $\sigma_0^2$, to find a probability distribution $p(x)$, whose variance is $\sigma_0^2$, that maximizes the overlap between the distribution and its Gaussian convolution of variance $\sigma_1^2$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,  dx\ p(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, dx'\ h(x') p(x-x'),
\end{align}
where $h(x)=\dfrac{e^{-x^2/(2\sigma_1^2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}$.

My guess is a Gaussian distribution with a given variance, but I don't know how to prove.